# What is the relationship between Graphs (graph theory) and logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, graph-theory, predicate-logic

I have read that Graph theory is useful to mathematical logic, but I don’t understand how. 
How exactly does a logic of graphs differ from standard predicate logic?

Here is an example from an article by [Van Benthem](http://home.hib.no/prosjekter/easllc2012/docs/liu/vanBenthem-Grossi-Liu-2012-priotity%20structure.pdf):

> 2.2 Priority graphs and derived betterness ordering

Deﬁnition 1 (P-graphs). Let L(P) be a propositional language built on the set of atoms P. A P-graph is a tuple G = 〈 Φ, ≺ 〉 such that:

– Φ ⊂ L(P) with | Φ | < ω;

– ≺ is a strict order on Φ : property ψ is strictly better than ϕ ; also, for all propositions ϕ , ψ ∈ Φ: if ϕ ≺ ψ then ϕ logically implies ψ .

Intuitively, a P-graph is a ﬁnite graph of formulae from a propositional language, where each formula logically implies its immediate successor in the order. In what follows, we will often drop the index referring to the current language.

P-graphs where ≺ is a strict linear order are called P-sequences, they are referred to as sequences 〈ϕ 1 , . . . , ϕ n 〉 of propositional formulae and are denoted by letter S. Given a P-graph G = 〈 Φ, ≺ 〉 we denote by S G the set of maximal P-sequences (i.e., ≺-chains) included in the order ≺”

I know graph theory is studied in Math, but I didn’t know there was a relationship with logic and with deontic logic, in particular.

Comment: Please give us a specific reference so we can respond appropriately. I have not read anything about "logic of graphs". There are many kinds of logic besides "standard predicate logic"

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but Frithjof Dau has a paper called "Mathematical Logic with Diagrams" which builds on C.S. Peirce's Existential Graphs.

Comment: @Nika I have quoted an article

Comment: @Somos I have edited the question and included an excerpt from an article

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me from the article by Benthem, that was is being described is a finite directed graph where a directed edge denotes immediate successor in the described order. This is not surprising. The idea of graphs is a very general one and directly models one aspect of a situation, namely an edge models a particular relation between the objects (whatever they are) corresponding to the vertices of the graph. The graph itself is not logic, but only models one particular aspect of a particular kind of logic. Certain aspects of that kind of logic can be expressed in the language of graph theory. Many other aspects can not.

Comment: Thank you! I will look for additional articles to see how it’s used as modelling tool in logic.